# Rotated constellation

Tags: simulink

I would like to know how to implement rotated 64QAM constellation under simulink? I have already initiate my transmission chain which should contain QAM mapping followed by constellation rotation then cell interleaver.But I didn't have any idea how to implement the block of rotated constellation.

Comment: Do you know how to implement it without rotation works?

Comment: yes a block already exist in simulink, simply insert your block and change the parameter

Comment: I don't have the corresponding toolbox, but everything you have to do is to rotate the output. Does it output a complex number or a vector? For the later you could use a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)